# I have a Flask app running on Mac that will need to manipulate files on a samba share, how do I ensure that it will always have access?

Tags: python, networking, samba

I'm writing an internal tool for my company that will need to probably always have access to a samba share. How can I always ensure that the drive is mounted at the same address /Volumes/... or have the Flask application connect with a Python library? Ultimately, I could just change the application to manipulate files on the local machine but it isn't preferable.

What would be the most sustainable / efficient way to implement?

Comment: I need you to clear something up, are you talking about mount persistance (i.e. ensuring the mount is always there on the client end) or ensuring that the share is very resilient at the server end?

Answer (score 1):

Although you're ultimately interacting with files using python, this question feels much more like one for [serverfault](http://serverfault.com) or [superuser](http://www.superuser.com), [both](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/samba) of [which](https://serverfault.com/tags/samba) have more samba-tagged questions [than stackoverflow does](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/samba).

As for the question itself, I am not intimately familiar with OSX, but on my linux installation I really like autofs, a system daemon that automatically mounts network file servers (including nfs and ssh also). See [this link](http://aj.tarachanowicz.com/?p=158) with some basic setup steps. Alternatively, of course, [there's always the standard way of connecting to network shares](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4011).